# Xcode old tab bar icons showing up unannounced

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

So in xcode I have a tab bar view controller with multiple tabs. Each tab has an individual tab bar icon. A while back I made my own custom icons and added them to my tab bar view controller, but just till recently I decided they don't look fitting. So I replaced them with sharper looking icons. The problem is when I run my app, it shows the old icons for a couple seconds, *then* shows the new icons. I've done clean/build many times in a vain attempt to cease this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems of this sort are almost always caused by the old icons hanging around inside your build. First, make sure you've really deleted them from your project. Then quit Xcode. Finally, follow the instructions here:

[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

Be sure to clean out both the DerivedData folder and the Simulator. Now there is no trace of the old build and you should get a proper clean build next time.

Comment: I have deleted them and restarted Xcode. As of now, taking a look at your link

Comment: Sorry, even deleting *everything* from my cache doesn't seem to work. I still see the old icons pop up for a few seconds when the app is loading, and when it fully loads the new icons appear

Comment: If that's true then they must be present in your project. Perhaps you should show the code or describe the process that loads your interface. It sounds to me like perhaps you're accidentally loading two interfaces, the old one followed shortly by the new one, or a single-resolution interface followed by a double-resolution interface, or something.

Comment: Oh, one more thought - if the absolute worst comes to the worst, start over with a clean project, building your app completely fresh from the ground up, copying in your code as needed. Hey, I've done that more than once. It often results in much better code.

Comment: I'm probably going to just do that. I shouldn't be fighting so hard for a little problem that I can fix by copy pasting my code to another project. And you're right; It'll give me time to revise my code and make it better.

Comment: And Xcode projects *can* get corrupted; I'm not saying it happened here, but it's possible. Hope things work out!